# Madcap Flare 11 - HTML5 output throws requirejs error - Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(C

Tags: javascript, jquery, flare, madcap

I am building the customer manual on frontend using Madcam Flare 11 HTML5 output and referring the below js file but getting the error **Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(C)**

```html
<script src="scripts/helpDoc/WHP/Default.js"></script>
```

After i load the Madcap library and runtime i am getting the below error. This error comes at very first time when i invoke the madcap flare methods.

```
 require.min.js:13 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { 'use strict';

var commonjsGlobal = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : {};

function commonjsRequire () {
    throw new Error('Dynamic requires are not currently supported by rollup-plugin-commonjs');
}

function unwrapExports (x) {
    return x && x.__esModule && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'default') ? x['default'] : x;
}

function createCommonjsModule(fn, module) {
    return module = { exports: {} }, fn(module, module.exports), module.exports;
}

var es6Promise = createCommonjsModule(function (module, exports) {
/*!
 * @overview es6-promise - a tiny implementation of Promises/A+.
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014 Yehuda Katz, Tom Dale, Stefan Penner and contributors (Conversion to ES6 API by Jake Archibald)
 * @license   Licensed under MIT license
 *            See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/master/LICENSE
 * @version   v4.2.5+7f2b526d
 */

(function (global, factory) {
    module.exports = factory();
}(commonjsGlobal, (function () { function objectOrFunction(x) {
  var type = typeof x;
  return x !== null && (type === 'object' || type === 'function');
}

function isFunction(x) {
  return typeof x === 'function';
}



var _isArray = void 0;
if (Array.isArray) {
  _isArray = Array.isArray;
} else {
  _isArray = function (x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === '[object Array]';
  };
}

var isArray = _isArray;

var len = 0;
var vertxNext = void 0;
var customSchedulerFn = void 0;

var asap = function asap(callback, arg) {
  queue[len] = callback;
  queue[len + 1] = arg;
  len += 2;
  if (len === 2) {
    // If len is 2, that means that we need to schedule an async flush.
    // If additional callbacks are queued before the queue is flushed, they
    // will be processed by this flush that we are scheduling.
    if (customSchedulerFn) {
      customSchedulerFn(flush);
    } else {
      scheduleFlush();
    }
  }
};

function setScheduler(scheduleFn) {
  customSchedulerFn = scheduleFn;
}

function setAsap(asapFn) {
  asap = asapFn;
}

var browserWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : undefined;
var browserGlobal = browserWindow || {};
var BrowserMutationObserver = browserGlobal.MutationObserver || browserGlobal.WebKitMutationObserver;
var isNode = typeof self === 'undefined' && typeof process !== 'undefined' && {}.toString.call(process) === '[object process]';

// test for web worker but not in IE10
var isWorker = typeof Uint8ClampedArray !== 'undefined' && typeof importScripts !== 'undefined' && typeof MessageChannel !== 'undefined';

// node
function useNextTick() {
  // node version 0.10.x displays a deprecation warning when nextTick is used recursively
  // see https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/410 for details
  return function () {
    return process.nextTick(flush);
  };
}

// vertx
function useVertxTimer() {
  if (typeof vertxNext !== 'undefined') {
    return function () {
      vertxNext(flush);
    };
  }

  return useSetTimeout();
}

function useMutationObserver() {
  var iterations = 0;
  var observer = new BrowserMutationObserver(flush);
  var node = document.createTextNode('');
  observer.observe(node, { characterData: true });

  return function () {
    node.data = iterations = ++iterations % 2;
  };
}

// web worker
function useMessageChannel() {
  var channel = new MessageChannel();
  channel.port1.onmessage = flush;
  return function () {
    return channel.port2.postMessage(0);
  };
}

function useSetTimeout() {
  // Store setTimeout reference so es6-promise will be unaffected by
  // other code modifying setTimeout (like sinon.useFakeTimers())
  var globalSetTimeout = setTimeout;
  return function () {
    return globalSetTimeout(flush, 1);
  };
}

var queue = new Array(1000);
function flush() {
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    var callback = queue[i];
    var arg = queue[i + 1];

    callback(arg);

    queue[i] = undefined;
    queue[i + 1] = undefined;
  }

  len = 0;
}

function attemptVertx() {
  try {
    var vertx = Function('return this')().require('vertx');
    vertxNext = vertx.runOnLoop || vertx.runOnContext;
    return useVertxTimer();
  } catch (e) {
    return useSetTimeout();
  }
}

var scheduleFlush = void 0;
// Decide what async method to use to triggering processing of queued callbacks:
if (isNode) {
  scheduleFlush = useNextTick();
} else if (BrowserMutationObserver) {
  scheduleFlush = useMutationObserver();
} else if (isWorker) {
  scheduleFlush = useMessageChannel();
} else if (browserWindow === undefined && typeof commonjsRequire === 'function') {
  scheduleFlush = attemptVertx();
} else {
  scheduleFlush = useSetTimeout();
}

function then(onFulfillment, onRejection) {
  var parent = trequire.min.js:13)
    at L (require.min.js:41)
    at Object.g [as require] (require.min.js:104)
    at requirejs (require.min.js:126)
    at MadCap.WebHelp.HelpSystem.LoadLanguage (Default.js:269)
    at Default.js:269
    at MadCap.WebHelp.HelpSystem.LoadBreakpoints (Default.js:269)
    at MadCap.WebHelp.HelpSystem.<anonymous> (Default.js:269)
    at XMLHttpRequest.OnreadystatechangeRemote (Default.js:241)
```

Comment: That's a stack trace, which is a start. Where's the code that generated it? Also this code looks minified, so that might make debugging a lot harder.

Comment: @tadman i have just updated the prettier version of stack trace.